# Journey Builder Interactions/Decisions across Business Units

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We are looking at using JB for a type of re-activation Journey. One of the high level requirements is if a Contact is active in 2 Business Units (brands) and we want to be able to base decision points on email activity within both brands. So if the contact has interacted with an email in BU A or BU B...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions that I can think of.

### Update Contact Data Activity

Use the Update Contact Data Activity after an Engagement Split Activity (to see if the Contact has opened or clicked the email) to update an field in a Shared Data Extension.

You will need to create a 1:1 cardinal relationship back to the Contact Record in an Attribute Group for the Shared Data Extension (using Contact Builder, for each Business Unit).

You can then use the field that you updated (using the Update Contact Data Activity) in a Decision Split Activity.

### Tracking Data Extension using Data Views

This involves:

1. Create a query to populate a Shared Data Extension using a [Data View](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_job/) to record email tracking information.
2. create a 1:1 cardinal relationship back to the Contact Record in an Attribute Group for the Shared Data Extension (in Contact Builder).
3. Use the Shared Data Extension (containing the tracking data) in a Decision Split Activity in your Interactions.